# How can distribute one table data to another table

Tags: sql

I have two tables `Orderapproval` and `stock`:

Table 1:  Orderapproval

| itemcode | approvalqty |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 25 |
| 2 | 10 |

Table 2: stock

| itemcode | stockqty | batch | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | aa | 2021-02-01 |
| 1 | 10 | bb | 2021-02-10 |
| 1 | 15 | cc | 2021-02-02 |
| 2 | 5 | dd | 2021-02-01 |
| 2 | 20 | aa | 2021-02-05 |

we have stock batch-wise.
when we get an order request for an item
we are trying to pick up items from the old batch first & so on
How can I get a result set like this:

| itemcode | qty | batch | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | aa | 2021-02-01 |
| 1 | 15 | cc | 2021-02-02 |
| 1 | 5 | bb | 2021-02-10 |
| 2 | 5 | dd | 2021-02-01 |

**I am trying as......**

Declare @StockTable table
(ItemCode int,BranchCode int,Qty int)
Insert Into @StockTable values
(1,       101,          5),
(1,       102,           10),
(1,       101,          15),
(2,       102,           5),
(2,       103,           20)

Declare @Orderapproval table (ItemCode int,Qty int)
Insert Into @Orderapproval values
(1,25),
(2,10)

;with T1 as (
Select A.*
,ToDist  = cast(D.Qty as int),
running_total = SUM(D.Qty) OVER (PARTITION BY  A.ItemCode,BranchCode  ORDER BY  BranchCode  DESC
ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
AND CURRENT ROW)

```
     From  @StockTable A
     
     Join  @Orderapproval D on A.ItemCode=D.ItemCode    )
```

, T2 as (
Select *,   prev_running_total = LAG(Qty,1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY  ItemCode ORDER BY  BranchCode  DESC) From T1

)

select *,
CASE WHEN prev_running_total >= ToDist THEN 0
WHEN running_total > ToDist THEN ToDist - prev_running_total
ELSE qty
END 'qty'
from T2;

I didn't get the right output.
Please suggest  a better way

Comment: Care to explain what the **logic** behind this result is?? Just dropping three "tables" on us is like a riddle - but not everyone likes to **guess** what it is you're trying to do! Please **EXPLAIN** in your own words

Comment: we have stock batch wise. pick old batch to new  and make qty  to issued equal to approval qty

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT s.itemcode
     , s.stockqty AS qty
     , s.batch
     , s.date
  FROM stock AS s
 INNER JOIN Orderapproval AS oa
    ON s.stockqty <= oa.approvalqty
```

If required, insert resultset into new table

Comment: how's this possible,
approvalqty  is in Orderapproval table not in stock table

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it

Comment: it's a simple query ,please see the output,batchwise qty should be equal to approvalqty

Answer (score 0):

SQL CODE---(Tested)

```
Select stock.itemcode
       ,stock.stockqty AS qty
       ,stock.batch,stock.date 
from stock 
join orderapproval on stock.stockqty <= orderapproval.approvalgty 
group by stock.batch;
```

Comment: what is the use of group by ?

Comment: it's a simple query ,please see the output,batchwise qty should be equal to  approvalqty

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on SQLite 3.30

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE stock (
  id INT,
  itemcode INT,
  stockqty INT,
  batch CHAR,
  date DATE
);
INSERT INTO stock (id, itemcode, stockqty, batch, date) VALUES (1, 1, 5, 'aa', '2021-02-01');
INSERT INTO stock (id, itemcode, stockqty, batch, date) VALUES (2, 1, 10, 'bb', '2021-02-10');
INSERT INTO stock (id, itemcode, stockqty, batch, date) VALUES (3, 1, 15, 'cc', '2021-02-02');
INSERT INTO stock (id, itemcode, stockqty, batch, date) VALUES (4, 2, 5, 'dd', '2021-02-01');
INSERT INTO stock (id, itemcode, stockqty, batch, date) VALUES (5, 2, 20, 'aa', '2021-02-05');

CREATE TABLE orderapproval (
  id INT,
  itemcode INT,
  approvalqty INT
);
INSERT INTO orderapproval (id, itemcode, approvalqty) VALUES (1, 1, 25);
INSERT INTO orderapproval (id, itemcode, approvalqty) VALUES (2, 2, 10);
```

Query:

```
with a as ( SELECT *, sum(stockqty) over (partition by itemcode order by date ) as acc FROM stock)
select a.itemcode, case when acc<=approvalqty then stockqty else approvalqty-(acc-stockqty) end as qty, batch, date from a 
inner join orderapproval o
on a.itemcode = o.itemcode
where qty > 0
order by a.itemcode, date
```

Result:

| itemcode | qty | batch | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | aa | 2021-02-01 |
| 1 | 15 | cc | 2021-02-02 |
| 1 | 5 | bb | 2021-02-10 |
| 2 | 5 | dd | 2021-02-01 |
| 2 | 5 | aa | 2021-02-05 |

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5WmC831LyLsBoHVRpifvN/1)

Comment: in `batch CC`  stock is 15. but your query taking ACC value  20,
it should be 15 and rest 5 qty from `batch BB`,
please suggest

Comment: @nazimtyagi I update my answer